# Are there any ways to assign strings from a list to a specific part of a table?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a timetable in Python. Are there any ways to assign the subjects inside the list into specific parts of the table?

```
subjects_name = ['LAW', 'PHYSICS', 'MARKETING', 'ACCOUNTING', 'MULTIMEDIA']

#expectet_output:
+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
|          |     Monday   |      Tuesday    |    Wednesday    |   Thursday   |    Friday   |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
|  8-10am  |     LAW      |                 |     MARKETING   |              |  MULTIMEDIA |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
|  10-12am |              |    PYHSCIS      |     MULTIMEDIA  |              |     LAW     |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
|  12-2Pm  |  ACCOUNTING  |                 |                 |  ACCOUNTING  |             |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: There are multiple ways, varying from nested dicts to using Pandas. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I already tried this method but the only problem is the table cant have empty spaces between subjects in the table.